# Compare list in prolog

Tags: list, variables, prolog

I just started learning prolog and i don't understand why this returning false. I tried find solutions, but i not found. Can someone tell me why this return false?

```
[[A],B,C]=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],1].
```

Comment: Because you here aim to match a list of three elements with a list `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f],1]`. Furthermore the first list should contain only one element (due to `[A]`), but it contains three elements.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: `[A]` is a *singleton* list, but the corresponding element `[a,b,c]` has three elements.

You aim to match `[[A], B, C]` with `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], 1]`. This thus means that you want to match a list with three elements with `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], 1]`. Furthermore it means that you want to match `[A] = [a,b,c]`, `B = [d,e,f]` and `C = 1`. The `[A]` can however *not* match with `[a,b,c]`, since `[A]` means a *singleton* list.

You probably want to match this with `[A,B,C]` instead:

```
?- [[A],B,C]=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],1].
false.

?- [A,B,C]=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],1].
A = [a, b, c],
B = [d, e, f],
C = 1.
```

If you want to match with a non-empty list, with `A` the first element, you can match this with `[A|_]` instead:

```
?- [[A|_],B,C]=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],1].
A = a,
B = [d, e, f],
C = 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to answer why your query fails using `library(diadem)`:

```
?- [[A],B,C]=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],1].
   false.
?- [[A],B,C]=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],1].?X.
   X = ([[A]|_]=[[_,_|_]|_])                        /* 1 */
;  X = (dif(A100,B100),[[A|A100]|_]=[[_|B100]|_])   /* 2 */
;  X = (dif(A100,B100),[A100|_]=[B100|_])           /* 3 */
;  X = (dif(A100,B100),A100=B100)                   /* 4 */
;  ... .
```

Here the system generates **most general generalizations** that still fail.

The first generalization removes all irrelevant parts, what remains is this `[A]` and `[_,_|_]`.

The second generalization insists that the tail of both lists is just different (instead of insisting that they are `[]` and `[_|_]` as stated in the first generalization).

The third and fourth are just more general views of it.